# Rails 3, Devise: change flash message on user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When users sign up, they have to confirm because I enabled the confirmable module of Devise.  This is the message they see:

```
You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is unconfirmed.
```

I checked the locale file and tried making some modifications:

```
registrations:
  signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
  inactive_signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is %{reason}.'
  ...
  reasons:
    inactive: 'inactive'
    unconfirmed: 'awaiting email confirmation.  Please check your email'
```

Is there a way to have `%{reason}` reference the message of reasons.unconfirmed instead of just using "unconfirmed"?

Answer (score 0):

Now [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) updated to version 2.0 [check this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0).

You can change this very easy.

```rb
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'Awaiting email confirmation. Check you email first!!.'
```